# How to find compatible cranks?

Tags: crankset, replacement

The threads on both cranks got busted due to putting the wrong pedals by the shop ([here is my post with details](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/27357/crank-threads-stripped-both-pedals-fell-off)) so I need to find replacement. How to find compatible cranks? My bike is Carrera Gryphon Hybrid 21" frame, 16 speeds, cranks are FSA Tempo, arm length is 175mm. The bike was sold by Halfords in 2012 but I couldn't find the technical info they gave me back than so these are the only details I know right now.

What else (other than the arm length and the 2 rings) do I need to look for? I tried looking for the part IDs online (A2F0953410 and A2F0964132) but nothing came up. Another ID I see printed on the back of the cranks is "CK-200-1 D" and "CK-C200". I tried searching for these but the cranks I found did not seem to be of the same type or size.

Here are photos of the backs of the cranks (photos of the fronts can be seen at the above link):

[image: Left crank]

[image: Right crank]

Can you point me to compatible cranks?

ps. I now realise that I haven't tried to look up the QR codes on the cranks - will try to do this tomorrow but if you have any suggestions in the meantime - please let me know.

Comment: Based on the level of damage to the old crank arms how do you conclude wrong pedals?  Pedal treads are pretty standard.  That looks more to me like cross threaded or seized up.

Comment: I believe that the shop fitted the pedals on the wrong sides - both pedals fell off, both crank threads damaged; but the strongest evidence is that the pedal on the right was not screwed in till the end (I noticed it before it fell), when I looked at the pedals in the morning for one of them it was obvious that it hasn't been screwed till the end (part of the thread was rusty) and that pedal was the LEFT. So I conclude that they must have had the pedals installed on the wrong sides.

Comment: I would suggest you replace the whole crank and bb - not just the arms.  Especially if the chain rings are not servicable (cannot be replaced).

Comment: @Blam: How to find compatible crank sets and bb? I've never sourced parts myself - this would be a first.

Comment: But you are posting the wrong pics.  Need to size to the BB.  You might as well just pull the crank and get the BB size.

Comment: I don't see a reason to swap the BB. In any case, youd need some extra tools for doing the BB, so you may as well take it to a shop. You're not going to find these exact cranks as they're probably OEM only, so go to your local bike shop and let them spec it up appropriately.

Comment: The critical features are 1) the sort of connection between crank arm and crank shaft, 2) the length of the arm (though this can be changed if you wish), and 3) how the chainrings mount.  Hard to be sure from the picture, but it appears that your chainrings are riveted to the crank, meaning they must be replaced as a set.

Comment: (And note that you can screw things up pretty bad if you do not properly install the crank arms, so you might be best off leaving this all to a shop.)

Answer (score 4):

Lets say you wish to replace a crank similar to yours and you cannot find the exact same crank as the one you have.

BIG PICTURE: Unless you can find the exact same crank as yours, you'll need to purchase both a crank and matching bottom bracket. A guide for choosing a crank is listed below

1. Measure the length of the Bottom Bracket shell. If it is 68mm or 73mm you're in good shape because thats a very common 'British' or 'ISO' size
2. Count how many chainrings you have. 1? 2? or 3? 1 is a little tricky as its hard to come by, 2 (yours looks like 2) is commonly a 'road bike crank' and 3 is commonly a Mountain bike crank, though there are also 3 for road bike too.
3. Count the teeth on the chainrings, or look for markings that may indicate the number of teeth (e.g.. 52teeth for the big one and 39teeth for the small chainring). If you like the gear ratios on your bike I suggest you stay with the same number with little deviation
4. Count how many cogs you have at the rear. 6,7,8,9,10,11? Anything 9 and below will allow many interchangeable cranks. 10 and 11 will require specific 10speed or 11 speed cranks ( i suspect yours is 8, thus you could get a crank designed for 9 speed or less. don't get one for a 10 speeder or higher)
5. Length of crank arm is less important for me. but you can select the same number as yours. 175mm
6. With that information, I'd suggest to get a crank and matching bottom bracket for your bike. If you are using a square taper or Octalink or similar Bottom bracket your replacement crank may fit in it, but the length of the spindle of the bottom bracket may be incorrect for your crank.. so its very tricky. for example for square taper bottom brackets there are about 6 or more different spindle lengths. getting the length wrong could mean incorrect chainlines and issues with the drive train. So unless you get the exact same replacement crank.. you'll need to get a matching bb to the crank.
7. At this juncture you might consider one of the HollowTech 2 cranks/bb from Shimano.. they work well and have less issues with spindle lengths though it may be challenging to get cranks for 9 speed or less unless they are old stocks.

Comment: Wow, thanks! This is really a very informative post. Just briefly replying to the questions you asked - yes, there are 2 chainrings, and, yes, it's 16 speed (8 cogs at the rear).

Comment: Ok thats good.. Its likely you'll be looking out for something that shops describe as a 'road' crank. You can confirm this by counting the teeth on your crank and comparing it with other road cranks on offer. The slightly tricky thing would be to find a new crank to support 8 or 9 speeds. as of today many shops will stock 10 speed versions and this is not ideal for reasons such as chain width, front shifting issues when mated to existing front derailleur. So its likely if you ascertain you need a road crank, you may want to shop for a 9 speed or 8 speed compatible. try older SORA or Tiagra

Answer (score 1):

It's a square taper (JIS) crankset. The [Vero](http://www.fullspeedahead.com/products/cranksets-road/vero-compact/) is a similar crank from Full Speed Ahead. However, any double chaining square taper crank will fit the bottom bracket. There's plenty of options with that in mind, especially if you're open to used.

If you want the same gearing, I'd suggest making sure the bolt circle diameter is the same. It should be 110cm. If the linear distance from one chainring bolt to the adjacent one is equivalent on both cranks, you're good to go.

It should be noted that 50/34 doubles are a relatively new phenomenon so the 110 bolt pattern is hard to find on old cranks.

Also, don't get a triple. You'll need to change all sorts of things.