# Damaged pedal threads on crank arms, having a hard time finding a replacement, what do I do?

Tags: crankset, chainring

I have the Vitus Nucleus 27 vr, but I recently broke the original plastic pedal on it after I hit a rock and so I replaced it with another set. The problem is I completely overtightened and damaged the thread on both cranks.

I need to replace the cranks, however every website I try to buy just the cranks, I am met with either having to buy the whole crankset or just being able to buy the left crank for some reason. Also I'm very concerned about the compatibility between all the components.

So what do I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you've damaged both threads, replacing the whole set might be the cheapest solution rather than having the damaged threads replaced with inserts. A picture would be helpful.

Comment: You might want to check with a local bike shop to see if they can helicoil the cranks; the prices I've heard from that are definitely comparable to an entirely new set of cranks (including a new chainring), which seems like it might be necessary since that 4-arm 76 bcd pattern seems uncommon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Crank threads stripped - both pedals fell off](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/27357/crank-threads-stripped-both-pedals-fell-off)

Comment: There seems to be a plethora of 32t narrow wide single-speed cranksets available in the $50US range - including bottom bracket.  Factor in the cost for a bottom-bracket tool if the replacement crankset doesn't use the same bottom bracket that's already on your bike, and even then it might be cheaper to just buy a new crankset, the tools to replace it, and replace it yourself.  It's not exactly difficult.  And if you can find a new crankset that is compatible with your current bottom bracket, it's even cheaper and easier.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to rescue the threads in the current crank with a thread tap.  Running the correct size back through the damaged threads might clean them up enough to work.

Failing that your LBS should be able to give you a price to Helicoil them.  Basically they increase the size of the hole and stick an insert in for the pedals to screw into.

Comment: This is good practical advise, but the costs need to be compared.  A general-purpose engineering shop might be capable, but pedal threads are 20 TPI not the common 18 TPI at 9/16".   So pedal thread helicoils are exceptionally specialised - only Bicycle pedals use them.

Comment: Also you need a left and right threads; Kits seem to be around $US200 with taps and coils for 10 sets of cranks, but unless skilled you would want an engineering shop to do it, last thing you want is a wonky pedal.  All still adds to cheaper to buy new cranks.